# typescript interface for specific json

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, interface

I wonder, how to create ts interface for this kind of JSON:

```
  "Cities": {

        "NY": ["New York", [8000, 134]],

        "LA": ["Los Angeles", [4000, 97]],

    }
```

I dont knot how to create this nested arrays and unique label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare the elements an array will contains:

```
interface IData {
  [key: string]: [
    string,
    [number, number]
  ];
}
```

`[number, number]` indicates the array contains exactly 2 elements of type `number`. The notation differs from `number[]` which indicates an array of `number`.